# How to override MessageCorrelationIDSelector for JMSReceive node via java Compute node

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus

I need to read the message from the JMS Queue and filter Messages based on the JMSCorrelationID in the middle of the flow. So i used JMSReceiveNode. The JMSCorrelationID is dynamic. So i try to over ride the MessageCorrelationIDSelector via java compute node as below. I added the correlationid tree in the local environment.

My java Compute node code:

`localEnv.getRootElement().createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME, "JMS", null).
                     createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME, "Receive", null).
                     createElementAsLastChild(MbElement.TYPE_NAME_VALUE, "MessageCorrelationIDSelector", dynamicID);'`

But am getting JMS destinaiton not found exception. If i remove the local MessageCorrelationIDSelector from local environment its works fine.

The local Environment tree as below

```
'LocalEnvironment
 JMS
         Receive                    MessageCorrelationIDSelector:CHARACTER:123457
```

Comment: Hello, Can you please put a bit more information about the destination error and about the configuration of your JMSReceive node ? Are you sure your "dynamicID" variable contains the JMS CORRELATION ID ? (the id you displayed in your post seems weird to me ...)

Comment: Insert
           Type:INTEGER:5
           Text:CHARACTER:Broker 'FOTESTINGNODE'; Execution Group 'default'; Message Flow 'SampleJMSReceiveNode'; Node 'ComIbmJMSClientReceiveNode::ComIbmJMSClientReceiveNode::ComIbmJMSClientReceiveNode' 
         Insert
           Type:INTEGER:5
           Text:CHARACTER: Not an ActiveMQDestination:ActiveMQQueue[createArrangementQueue], JMS Provider Destination is not available null ... the above exception am getting

Comment: @Jérém Yes the dynamic id in the JMSQueue and Setting dynamic id local environment is same correct.  But the thing is if i try to override the Correlation id via  LocalEnv then am getting the above error.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I'm not used to the JMS related nodes since I use IBM MQ; but I would suggest you to override all the required properties in the localEnv as a test. It looks like you loose the other properties configured on your node when you override one single param with the localEnv, which is not a normal behaviour.

Comment: @Jérém thanks for the update. Yes it worked as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LocalEnvironment
JMS
        Receive
                MessageCorrelationIDSelector:CHARACTER:='1111'
                Source:CHARACTER:createArrangementQueue
                QCF:CHARACTER:jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
                JNDIBindingLocation:CHARACTER:http-remoting://localhost:9089
                InitialContextFactory:CHARACTER:org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
                JMSProvider:CHARACTER:jboss71JMS
```

As @Jérém mentioned its working fine. We need to override all the properties as like above.

Comment: I'm glad to ear it helped, but this behaviour is not normal, all the other nodes accept that. If you have the possibility, please create a ticket for IBM (PMR) so they can fix it, this solution is just a workaround.